# Horizontal LinearLayout with "enabled/selected" border

Tags: android, android-layout

I try to find a nice(r) solution to my current layout problem:

I have a LinearLayout with 2 TextViews and 2 ImageViews and of each pair of views (text or image) one can be selected which should be displayed as a bottom border / underline.

Right now I use the following approach: I wrap every single one of those views in another LinearLayout and use like this as background (background is my bottom border):

drawable\preferred_border:

```
    <item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-3dp"
    android:right="-3dp"
    android:top="-3dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/nd_blue" />

        <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF" />


    </shape>
</item>
```

(it's a "hack" I found on stackoverflow to add a bottom border)

This approach works very nice but has one disadvantage: The distance between text/image and it's border is done via a paddingBottom of the innermost view (the border is set as a background in yet another wrapping LinearLayout). Now if the text and the images have not the same height, the bottom borders don't align in their vertical position!

Example of how it looks in my app:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/preferred_border">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/one"

                android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/wrapper_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/preferred_border">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/twot"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/two"

                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Same for the pair of ImageViews except it's obviously using an ImageView. The whole stuff is also packed into one RelativeLayout.

Right now I try to align them as best as I can by adjusting the padding and image sizes a little bit, but it is not a nice way to do this. I was hoping there is a clean solution using good layout skills in android :p

Thanks for any help / advice!

Comment: check my ans it will defenately work

Comment: did you check my ans ...if you get it than mark it as accept

Comment: why would it work? (it doesn't) the question is not about how to add a border but how to vertically align borders which are drawn as background in multiple Views!!